# plugins_url vs plugin_dir_url

Tags: functions

Im seeing WordPress plugins either use plugins_url or plugin_dir_url when creating constants to some of their folders. Is one better than the other?

examples:

```
define( 'MEMBERS_URI', trailingslashit( plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) ) );
define( 'WPACCESS_INC', plugins_url( 'inc', __FILE__ ) , true );
```

Comment: Note - you don't need to use `trailingslashit()` for  `plugin_dir_url()` because it already uses it within function.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Checkout - [wp-includes/plugin.php#L585](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/plugin.php#L585)

`plugin_dir_url()` function internally uses `plugins_url()` to get the link to plugin directory.

### plugin_dir_url()

This will return url of the plugin directory with a trailing slash at the end. So this can be easily used to link to the plugin directory.

> e.g - `http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/foo/`

### plugins_url

If no arguments are passed this will deliver the same result as the above function; but with or without a trailing slash at the end. This can be configured to link to files within plugin directory; a useful shortcut.

> e.g -
>
> `plugins_url( 'img/bar.jpg' , __FILE__ )` will return a url like
> `http://www.example.com/wp-content/plugins/foo/img/bar.jpg`

Comment: Why couldn't the WordPress documentation writes figure out how to explain this...! Well, they have never impressed me to say the least...