# When would I use either function for plugins?

Tags: plugin-development

I am curious as there are three function for loading files in plugins:

`plugin_dir_path()` and `plugins_url()`, along with `plugin_dir_url()` So as a plugin developer, which would you use for loading php files? the main example shows: `plugin_dir_path()` - but if one were to write an auto loader function, which function would you use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Return values of the three mentioned functions

**1.** [`plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_path) returns the servers *filesystem directory path* pointing to the current file, i.e. something along the lines of
 `/home/www/your_site/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/includes/`

This can be used for loading PHP files.

**2.** [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) returns the *web address* of the current WordPress installation's plugin folder, i.e. something along the lines of
`http://example.com/wp-content/plugins`

**3.** [`plugin_dir_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) behaves in a very similar fashion to [`plugins_url()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url). It also returns a *web address*, but with a trailing slash, i.e. something along the lines of
`http://example.com/wp-content/plugins/`

The latter two are useful to load images, stylesheets, JS and the like.

### Use-cases

Use-cases as from the main plugin file:

```
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'plugin_prefix_install' );

require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/class-plugin-sometask.php' );

wp_register_script(
    'your-script-handle',
    plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/your-script.js',
    false,
    '1.0',
    true
);

load_plugin_textdomain(
    'your-text-domain',
    false,
    basename( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages/'
);
```

Comment: Please don't pollute the global namespace with new constants! Slow, ugly and not collision-safe – that's anything but elegant.

Comment: If you say so @toscho, I am willing to believe. And reconsider my approach. Leave this or remove?

Comment: why with the plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) does it got to /includes/ ? @JohannesPille

Comment: @TheWebs That will point to the *absolute filesystem path* of the *current file* it is used in - hence, whether it will give you a subfolder depends on the loacation of the file it was called from.

Comment: Your examples are good and helpful. Add the functions where their return value is actually used, and it is fine.

Comment: @JohannesPille so I can just use  plugin_dir_path and it will go the root of the plugin directory for my plugin? - this works perfectly, thank you.

Comment: Aight, updated the use-cases with direct examples and eliminated the defining as constants step.

Comment: Great detailed answer!

Answer (score 3):

`plugin_dir_path()` is the only one of the three that gives you the local *filesystem* path, ie: `/var/www/site.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/`, and would be used for loading php files.

The other two are for retrieving public-facing URLs for loading assets like images, CSS, and JS files, ie: `http://site.com/wp-content/plugins/your-plugin/`.

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/61698/4771) explains the difference between `plugins_url()` and `plugin_dir_url()`.

Comment: +1, concise. Somewhat redundant, that I answered this as well, but I was halfway there when I got notified things had been done already.

Comment: Is there a reason to use `plugin_dir_path()` in code that resides in the plugin? Why not simply use a include like this? `include 'lib/options.php'` ?

Comment: Answering myself: Yes there is... - To avoid unintentionally including a file in the include path. 
"Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing." (http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)