# Calling a WordPress Custom JavaScript file

Tags: javascript

```
// Creates the function
function my_custom_javascript()
{ 
  // Loads the script into the function
  wp_enqueue_scripts('my_custom_javascript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery')); 
}
// calls the function where the script is located
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_javascript');
```

I think this is written right. I am calling this script in the functions.php file in my theme but it's not loading, so I was hoping I could get some suggestions.

Comment: Note that the correct function would be `wp_enqueue_script()`, not `wp_enqueue_scripts()`. Have you tried that and it's just a typo in your question?

Comment: Everything is working now...Sweet.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the function [`wp_enqueue_scripts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/) where you should be using **[`wp_enqueue_script()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/)**.

```
function my_custom_javascript(){ // Creates the function
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my_custom_javascript',
        plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . '/assets/js/custom.js',
        array('jquery')
    ); // Loads the script into the function
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_javascript'); 
// calls the function where the script is located
```

`wp_enqueue_script()` enqueues the script; `wp_enqueue_scripts()` is a wrapper for `do_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts' )`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_scripts('my_custom_javascript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_javascript');
```

** You don't need to use trailing slash before assets/js/custom.js because plugin_dir_url outputs it. Instead you can use plugins_url and you should use wp_enqueue_script NOT wp_enqueue_scripts while enqueuing file

I think this will help you: [plugins_url vs plugin_dir_url](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/61679/plugins-url-vs-plugin-dir-url/61698#61698)

Answer (score 0):

To cue your script you want to use [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) instead of [wp_enqueue_scripts()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/) like so.

```
function my_custom_javascript() {
    wp_enqueue_script('my_custom_javascript', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'assets/js/custom.js', array('jquery'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_javascript');
```

You don't need to add the / slash before assets/js/custom.js because plugin_dir_url uses [trailingslashit()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/trailingslashit) to include it.

If you really want to add the / yourself, you use [plugins_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) which gets called anyway minus the trailingslashit()